No sound after switching to Ubuntu 22.04 on new laptop
I recently purchased a new HP Envy after my old one died on me. I cannot stand Windows so I installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on it. I have no sound through the laptop's speakers. I can use bluetooth connection to listen to audio. I have tried many of the solutions people have shown online, but have not found a real solution. The following are what are what I can find are currently on my laptop for audio.
  sof-hda-dsp
  Realtek ALC245
  Pulseaudio
  ALSA
Does anyone know what could be going on that it is not recognizing the onboard speakers?
update: I was able to listen to bluetooth at first but now that is not working either. I have no idea why this would suddenly stop working but now I have zero way to get audio from my laptop. This is incredibly frustrating.

Does this answer your question? No more sound in Ubuntu 18.04 HP Envy

I tried this already but it did not fix the issue.

Why was this question downvoted?

To be honest, I'd try to go with Ubuntu 24.04 beta directly since it has all the newest packages.
I have a laptop, I had audio issues, but different.
Laptop audio: OK
External audio with monitor: not working until installing Nvidia drivers
Another time, for who knows which reasons, Ubuntu totally messed up the audio and I couldn't hear anything from any source on any OS (Windows 11 too). I had to do an EC reset.

I have the HP ENVY x360 2-in-1 Laptop 13-bf0xxx
I also had no sound on the laptop speakers.
I installed unsigned Linux kernel 6.9-rc 1 and that fixed the problem.
I think the driver for this soundcard in the kernel shipped with Ubuntu 22.04 and 23.10 is is not working properly and is patched in newer kernels.
Currently i am on the developer version of Xubuntu Noble Numbat with the above mentioned kernel and now i have sound working fine. Even the kernel that comes with 24.04 does not make my speakers work.
if you want to give it a try you might use this guide to test a newer unsigned linux kernel for wich you have to disable secure boot in the bios. https://itsfoss.com/upgrade-linux-kernel-ubuntu/ version 6.8 might also work.
this question is related i think: Ubuntu 23.04: No Speaker Sound with Realtek ALC245 on HP ENVY Laptop

I had a similar problem that started out last week with no sound and seemed to be related to pulse-audio. But, I think it had something to do with a faulty download of Jammy LTS that was causing errors in pulse-audio dependencies. I don't want to waste your time, I have very limited computer knowledge, but have you tried delete/reinstalling pulse-audio? Failing that, what about reinstalling Jammy LTS?

I have already tried that but it did not fix the issue.
